# Simperium OSX Starting Issue

Tags: macos, simperium

I am now starting the 2nd phase of my app development. I have a fully working iOS app on the app store syncing happily away using Simperium, I am now turning my attention to the OSX version of the app.

I have followed the instructions for OSX all look sweet but one question....

1) The "Don't have an account" button dosen't work in the Simperium build I have. I recall seeing awhile ago that you have a branch that fixes this, but can't find the branch now, can you point me in the right direction?

THANKS !

Steve

Answer (score 0):

OSX is fully supported in the latest develop branch, including the creation of new accounts.